# Defining Function Python

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a function that has one parameter that returns True if all the characters in the string are upper case or lower case ASCII letters, and the string is not empty. I want it to return False otherwise. I can tell I'm doing this all wrong.

```
ASCII_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ASCII_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
DECIMAL_DIGITS = "0123456789"


def is_alpha(a_string):   
    if a_string in ASCII_LOWERCASE or ASCII_UPPERCASE:
            for i in ASCII_LOWERCASE or ASCII_UPPERCASE:
            return "True"
```

Comment: `s.upper()` and `s.lower()` can also be useful to avoid the first 2 strings containing all the letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost correct. Here is a working version:

```
ASCII_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ASCII_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
DECIMAL_DIGITS = "0123456789"


def is_alpha(a_string):
    if not a_string:
        return False
    for c in a_string:
        if not (c in ASCII_LOWERCASE or c in ASCII_UPPERCASE):
            return False
    return True


print is_alpha('')
print is_alpha('ABCabc')
print is_alpha('ABC123')
```

results:

```
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a built-in function for this.

```
>>> "Hello one".isalpha()
True
>>> "Hello 2".isalpha()
False
>>> "".isalpha()
False
```

You can also import ascii letters:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation, ascii_lowercase
```

Don't re-invent the wheel :'D